How do you remove the doors of a living room stove?
Our living room has a stove with broken glass. I'd like to replace the glass.
Looking at the doors from the inside, I see a few screws holding the glass in place. The following pictures shows the broken glass and the screws:

I've tried to put some oil on those screws, but since it is vertical, most of the oil just goes down, not in where it would help with making it possible to unscrew the glass.
So I was thinking to remove the door which I can then place flat somewhere (like my workbench in the garage) and put oil on those screws there. It would probably also be much more practical to get the size of the glass in order to get a replacement and install said replacement.
So my question is: how would I get the hinges to let me take the doors off? I am thinking that I'm having the same issue as with the screws. I put some oil on the hinges, but so far I have not been able to make it bulge even one bit. The top hinges, I suppose I could use a hammer and "gently" hit them going up. The bottom hinges, however, there is no space to do that. It's way too close to the bottom of the stove.
Here is a picture from the front with the doors close. You can see the 4 hinges. The two bottom one really close to the cinder catcher.

And a picture of the other door:


Update: Oh! As mentioned in the answer, placing a screw driver near the head and turning to get the peg to come out worked. I first tried on the on that showed a little bit of game (see picture of the left door, the top peg has a small gap near the top, between its head and the door hinge).
I've taken a picture of the pegs. They are both very similar and round.


Have a feeling you just need to lift the door straight up.  A long ply bar under the corner might help.

The door may need to be in a particular position (fully closed, 90-degrees open, etc.) in order for the doors to just lift up off the hinges. Also, the dome-looking top of each hinge may come off to reveal a fastener, clip, etc.

Try spraying some WD-40 on the pins. Then tap a slotted screwdriver into the crack below the heads of each pin and try to loosen them up. Also try grabbing each pin head with an adjustable wrench/pliers and twist them back and forth while exerting an upward force.

Ah. I only have some 3-in-1. I'll try WD-40 instead. It may be much more effective. Now I don't think I'd want to use pliers on the pins. The idea is that they look good... pliers are likely to scratch them really bad.

Looking at my pictures, I noticed that the left door has a bit of game. So I decided to try removing the peg with a screw driver and it worked! I've updated my question showing the removed pegs (and the screw driver).

A penetrating lubricant, like WD-40 Specialist, perhaps.  Or AeroKroil, or PB Blaster.
